# How to open a link using Jquery from HTML, getting the URL from MySql and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

I have a database (MySql), inside the database there is a row with the URL of the images, (the images are in a folder), through PHP I am loading those images inside the HTML, and those images have a link, which should open a new HTML page inside the same div, into the same HTML.

I am trying with this code, but it is not working, it is still opening the new HTML page in another window, and not into the same div... I hope someone can help me, I would appreciate it so much!, thanks!!.

Here is the code.

```
<?php
include("conect.php");
$consulta= "SELECT id, company, type_company, work_type, img_link, image FROM logos" or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query($consulta);                   
$resultado=mysql_query($consulta) or exit( mysql_error() );

while($fila=mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){ 
?>   
        <div class="img_workLeft" id="img<?php echo ($fila['id']);?>">
        <a href="<?php echo ($fila['img_link']);?>" id="openjob" target="_self"><?php echo "<img src=".$fila['image'].">";?></a>
    </div>
<?php
}
    mysql_close();       
?>
```

HERE IS THE JQUERY CODE.

```
$(document).on("ready",_init);
    function _init(){
        clickdeBotones();
    }

function clickdeBotones(){
    $("#openjob").click(function(){
    $('#containerportfolio').load("#openjob");
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the load function a url, not an element selector.

Reference to [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

**Edit:**

```
function clickdeBotones(){
    $("#openjob").click(function(){
        $('#containerportfolio').load("page.php");
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate for helping me, but in the code I am getting the URL dynamically from the database with PHP, inside the "a href", so if I do what you said, it will open just a single page... and by the way it is opening in another window... :-S

Comment: You can add whatever variable string you'd like where I have entered `"page.php"`. As long as you have an element with id `containerportfolio` then the content loaded dynamically from the page you provide should be loaded into that element. I don't know why it would be loaded into a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

This should work together with your HTML/PHP Code.

```
$(document).on("ready",_init);
    function _init(){
        clickdeBotones();
    }

function clickdeBotones(){
    $("#openjob").click(function(){
    $('#containerportfolio').load($('#openjob').attr('href'));
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you are echoing more than one openjob link, you will have several links with the same id. You may want to just assign it a class, and use the jquery class selector `$(".myclass")` as such:

**Markup**:

```
<div class="img_workLeft" id="img<?php echo ($fila['id']);?>">
    <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/" class="openjob" target="_self"><img src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" /></a>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class="openjob" target="_self"><img src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" /></a>
</div>
<div id="containerportfolio">
</div>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(".openjob").click(function(){
    $('#containerportfolio').load($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

<kbd>[Live Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/cWnbp/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks mate. That's not happening, in fact, the links are opening each page perfectly, because the link is coming from the database as well, so when I get the image, the image has their own link and that is opening perfectly. The problem is that when I do click in the image, it is opening the link (as should do) but not into the div that I want...

Comment: Sorry mate, I am having hard time understanding what you need. What exactly do you want opened into the container portfolio? The link inside "href" of a tag? or the image? or what?

Comment: I am sorry mate, maybe I am not explain it very well... thanks for your help and patience.

I have this HTML page (a gallery) where I am loading 9 images thumbnails, from MySQL through PHP, each image has their own single page. The URL is into the database, each thumbnail has their own link. In this moment each image is opening the corresponding HTML page (as should do it), but what I want to do is open that page, into a div in this case is $('#containerportfolio')

Answer (score 0):

I tried   to edit Thomas answer but i couldnt. This worked for me.

```
$(document).on("ready",_init);
        function _init(){
            clickdeBotones();
        }

    function clickdeBotones(){
        $("#openjob").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#containerportfolio').load($('#openjob').attr('href'));
    });
    }
```